# Is my routing for nested has_many through: associations correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a rails API app with three main models: User, Article, and Annotation (annotations = create notes for parts of an article), and two support join models: Article_View_History and Annotation_View_History

A user can create articles as well as view them. The article_view_history table keeps track of which user has viewed which article.

A user can create annotations under each article as well as view them. The annotation_view_history table keeps track of which user has viewed which annotation.

Is what I have in the routes.rb file correct?

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  has_many :viewed_articles, through: :article_view_histories
  has_many :article_view_histories

  has_many :annotations
  has_many :viewed_annotations, through: :annotation_view_histories
  has_many :annotation_view_histories
end
```

Annotation.rb

```
class Annotation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :annotation_view_histories
  has_many :viewed_users, through: :annotation_view_histories
end
```

Article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :article_view_histories
  has_many :viewed_users, through: :article_view_histories

  has_many :annotations
end
```

AnnotationViewHistory.rb

```
class AnnotationViewHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :viewed_users, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :user_id
  belongs_to :viewed_annotations, :class_name => "Annotation", :foreign_key => :annotation_id
end
```

ArticleViewHistory.rb

```
class ArticleViewHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :viewed_users, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :user_id
  belongs_to :viewed_articles, :class_name => "Article", :foreign_key => :article_id
end
```

routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users, :skip => :sessions, controllers: {registrations: 'api/registrations', passwords: 'api/passwords', confirmations: 'api/confirmations'}, defaults: { format: :json }

  use_doorkeeper do
    skip_controllers :applications, :authorized_applications, :authorizations
  end

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, path: '/' do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resource :users, only: [:show] do
        resource :articles do
          resource :annotations
        end
        resource :article_view_histories
        resource :annotation_view_histories
      end
    end

    match '*path', to: -> (env) {
    [400, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' },
      [{ status: 404, error: 'Route Not Found' }.to_json]]
      }, via: :all
  end
```